# Apply SVG Gradient filter to background image

Tags: css, svg

I found this SVG code, and I was wondering how do I apply it to a background image?

```
<svg width="600px" height="600px" viewbox="0 0 600 600">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="alphaLinear">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0%" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="100%" />
        </linearGradient>

        <mask id="Mask">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600" fill="url(#alphaLinear)"  />
        </mask>
    </defs>

    <image xlink:href="/media/images/body-bg.jpg" width="600" height="600" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" mask="url(#Mask)"/>
</svg>
```

In the `<image>` tag I replaced the href url with the image I want to use. I then call the svg from the css like so:

```
body{
     background: url('/media/images/gradient.svg') center top no-repeat;
}
```

Nothing seems to be happening, all I am getting is a white background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong:

1. For external files, you will need the `xmlns` and `xmlns:xlink` namespace declarations in the `<svg>` tag.

   ```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="600px" height="600px" viewbox="0 0 600 600">
   ```
2. `viewbox` should be `viewBox`
3. SVG files used as an external image in `<img>` or as a `background-image` need to be self contained.  They cannot refer to other external files as you are doing here.

   You can embed the external JPEG as a Data URI though if you want.

   ```
   <image xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,...Base64 encoded JPEG data here...">
   ```

Comment: That does it, but is there anyway to do it without base64 encoding it? I remember doing something where all I had to do was apply the filter to a jpg image without referencing it in the svg.

Comment: You could use an HTML `<img>` element and apply an SVG filter to it.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example_Filtering and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters